# How to play greensock timeline max based on a data attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, gsap

Currently I am not getting an answer at the greensock forum. I have a searchbar, which should expand by clicking on an icon and close again, when clicking anywhere at the body, but only, when the searchbar is expanded.

When I open the searchbar I am facing two problems for the closing animation:

(1) The closing animation is being resetted when I click on the body element while the closing animation is running.

(2) The closing animation runs, even if the searchbar is not expanded.

I tried to solve this issues by adding a data attribute to the container for the different states (open, true/false) but somehow it does not work as intended. Is there any logic error in my code?

```
(function($) {

var $irpsearch = $('#irp-newssearch-container'),
    $irpsearchinput = $('#irp-searchform-input'),
    $search_icon = $('.irp-news-search-icon'),
    $btn_container = $('.irp-filter-buttons'),
    $filter_btn = $('.filter-btn'),
    $search_seperator = $('.irp-search-seperator')
    $body = $('body');

    var openSearchAnimation = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        })
        openSearchAnimation
            .staggerTo($filter_btn, .5, {scale: 0.7 ,opacity: 0,ease: Back.easeInOut},-0.1)
            .set($btn_container,{'display': 'none'})
            .to($search_seperator, .3, {opacity: 0, ease: Expo.easeOut}, '-=0.6')
            .to($search_icon, .5, {backgroundColor:"#ffffff", ease: Power0.easeNone}, '-=1.0')
            .to($irpsearch, 1.0, {width: '100%', ease: Power3.easeOut}, '-=0.1');

    openSearch = function () {
        $irpsearch.data('open', true);
        openSearchAnimation.play();
        $irpsearchinput.focus();
        return false;
    },
    closeSearch = function() {
        $irpsearch.data('open', false);
        openSearchAnimation.reverse(0);
    }

/*$irpsearchinput.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    });*/

$irpsearch.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!$irpsearch.data('open')) {

        openSearch();

        /* HTML Click */
        $body.off('click').on('click', function(e) {
            closeSearch();
        });

        /* Escape Hide */
        $( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
            if ( e.keyCode === 27 ) { // ESC
                closeSearch();
            }
        });


    } else {
        if ($irpsearchinput.val() === '') {
            closeSearch();
            return false;
        }
    }
});

})(jQuery)
```

Codepen to illustrate the issues:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQqQWm

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details as to what is the final result that you are looking for? As I understand first of all the animation should not close until it has opened completely. Secondly do you also want the closing animation to start by clicking anywhere?? Give me more data and I will surely help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed a few things and hope this is what you're looking for.

The main difference is that we now bind our events with `.one(...)` instead of `.on(...)`. This means that the event will only get executed once and then destroyed and we don't have to keep track of the state.

When the site loads we bind `$irpsearchinput.one('focus', ...)`.
The event will be executed when the `input` gets focus.

Within the function `openSearch` we bind `$ripsearchinput.one('blur', ...)` (executed when the `input` loses focus) and inside the function `closeSearch` we again bind `$irpsearchinput.one('focus', ...)`.

Lastly we make sure that when you press `ESC` the `input` loses focus (and thereby triggers the `blur`-binding.

Here's a [fork](https://codepen.io/IvanModric/pen/JJLadv) of your pen.

Comment: Thanks! I was on vacation, but this is difenetley what I was looking for :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)